Near optimally doped superconductors' Ba isotope effect data precision
Is there any freely available transition temperature data for p-type cuprate superconductor samples around optimal oxygen content as a function of average barium isotope mass in a sample and oxygen content? (the latter can be just a guess based on temperatures and partial pressures of oxygen gas in an annealing atmosphere, where the sample is made)
The closest thing I found by searching google was an old experimental description in Russian language (I'm not good at Russian). After translating it appears that they varied barium isotopes in YBCO but oxygen content was kept constant at optimal value.
In order to test my theory, I need precise data near (not only at) optimal oxygen concentration, so if I had designed these experiments, I would use the same samples again after diffusing some oxygen out by re-annealing in an inert atmosphere. Unfortunately, I'm not a professional chemist nor physicist.

I assume you are referring to a specific material? Not all hole doped cuprates contain Ba. Are you only interested in BSSCO?

What is BSSCO? Did you mean BSCCO? BSCCO does not, however, contain any barium. In any case, I did not refer to any specific material. Any barium containing hole doped layered cuprate will do. In fact, lanthanum may do as well, but that is another question and is unlikely to be observed due to the rarity of La-138.

Sorry, ignore my brain-added first comment. I meant barium not bismuth. Given that the superconductivity in cuprates is very two-dimensional and resides in the copper oxide plane, it is not obvious that there should be much isotope effect in the spacer layer atom species. Is your theory in the spirit of a BCS like isotope effect?

No, it isn't BCS-like. It predicts higher transition temperature for higher Ba mass in slightly underdoped regime and also a lower optimal hole content for higher Ba mass. The effect is bigger in materials with higher fraction of Ba.
